# How to access the control id lying inside datalist in the js in same file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the code below in the same aspx page.I want to access the value of textbox in the js but the txtName(id) is not recognized.

```
<asp:DataList ID="Dl_products" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text="wtf" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var name = document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID %>").value;
    alert(name);
</Script>
```

Comment: A `DataList` generally has more than one record.  Which record are you trying to access?  Look at the actual generated client-side code, what are the element `id`s?  `id`s can't repeat, so the `DataList` isn't going to use the same `id` for every record.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via jquery like this

```
$('input[id$=txtName]').val();
```

But Datalist would have multiples textboxes so id would not be same as this.